# Jquery Flot - how to get the data lines to start at 0,0 and go to the first data point

Tags: jquery, flot

I`m using the library Flot (Jquery) to draw graphs in webApp, but i have a problem.
I want to draw the point (0,0) (by doing a push of an array [0,0]) but the problem is that XAXES are Dates.
And the point it draws is "1970/01/01 00:00" and my other points in the graph gets lost at the final of the graph. Something like the next graph!!!!!

```
 8|                     /.(a)  
  |                  /   .(e)  
 6|               /            
  |            /         .(i)  
 4|         /            .(o)  
  |      /                     
 2|   /                  .(u)  
  |/_________________________
 (m)


(m)         Point(0,0), drew: "1970-01-01- 00:00"
(a),...,(u) My Points, eg.: (8,"2013-09-20"),(7,"2013-09-19"),(5,"2013-09-18"),(4,"2013-09-17"),(2,"2013-09-16")
```

May someone help with this problem?????
 i will appreciate any help!! Thanks you in advance!!!

Comment: If your x-axis is a time axis, then why do you want a point zero?  It doesn't make much sense to go from 0 to 2013-09-20 on an axis.

Comment: A real image (before and after adding the point (0,0)), your data array and your code would help with answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a point (0,0) to your graph you have to make clear at which date / time this point should be in the graph.

The literal date value 0 is 1970-01-01 as you can see because this is the start point for javascript date values. So if you want the graph to start at e.g. 2013-09-01 you have to add the point (0,"2013-09-01") to your data array instead of the point (0,0).

Additionally you have to add your data points in the format [timestamp, value]. To get the timestamp for a given date use `new Date("2013-09-20").getTime()`. More explanations in the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data).

Comment: Thanks Raidri
What i need is that my first point (e.g.: (2,"2013-09-16") ) does not be placed in (0,0) position. I want it were a little more at right but it has to be connected to a point (0,0)

thanks so much!!!